# High CPU usage by apache/httpd for light load, 'perf record' points at vmware/hardware

Tags: linux, performance, vmware-esxi, httpd, perf

Running Apache 2.4 on RHEL7 kernel 3.10.0-1062, 4 CPU VMWare instance, doing very basic reverse proxying to WebLogic backend using WebLogic proxy plugin. Server is only pushing around 1 MByte/sec with a couple hundred users, listening for SSL and also talking SSL to WebLogic. Apache configuration is very basic, only a couple RewriteRule lines or other typical performance sinks. VMWare stats show no overcommit but also show guest CPU utilization at 100%.

From Linux POV the server is sitting with 100% CPU utilization and a run queue going over 16, with Apache using all CPU time. Running 'perf record -a -g' for a minute and creating a flamegraph shows that in httpd process (using 97% of all CPU, per flamegraph) we have these surprising usages of time:

- ktime_get_ts64 -> read_tsc - 20.5% of all CPU samples, seems to just run rdtsc instruction
- system_call_after_swapgs - 13.24% of all CPU samples, seems to refer to the fairly concise code at https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.S?h=linux-3.10.y#n625

Basically outside those two remarkable outliers, all runtime is spent inside two libc calls, poll_nocancel and read_nocancel, coming from both apache's listening loop and the WebLogic plugin's outgoing traffic, which lead to those swapgs and readtsc calls among others.

Underlying hardware seems fine, Linux kernel parameters seem fine, but it feels like the actual instructions per second being executed on this server is very slow. Any advice for further anaylsis using 'perf' tool? I have no access to the server so can only suggest commands for others to run.

Comment: Please include that flame graph. Even a still image without the fancy .svg is much better at illustrating the problem compared to a description of it.

Comment: Can you try this, hovering over allows showing the original document - https://sendeyo.com/en/bdf8e1ffdc

Answer (score 2):

That flamegraph of yours in static format, cropped to remove skinny deep stacks:

[image: flamegraph showing read_tsc]

Yes, much of the on-CPU samples are system call related. Lots of poll() and the resulting read_tsc(), some read(), and apparently some system call overhead given time spent in system_call_after_swapgs().

Now this becomes a search for performance bugs and inefficiencies in *all* layers of your infrastructure. An incomplete list of ideas:

### Hypervisor

Regarding TSC on VMware, see [KB 65186](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/65186)

> ### Performance issue when TSCs are incorrectly detected to be unsynchronized (65186)
>
> Symptoms During boot, the vmkernel logs a message containing the
>   phrase "TSC disabled as reference timer: multiple clock domains" or
>   "TSC disabled as reference timer: diverging NUMA TSCs".
>
> Subsequently, virtual machines show unusually poor performance when
>   executing the rdtsc instruction.
>
> Cause 
>   On most modern x86-compatible
>   machines, hardware ensures that the TSC (timestamp counter) registers
>   of all logical CPUs are synchronized at boot time and remain always in
>   sync with each other unless changed by software, so the TSCs can be
>   treated as a single global reference timer.  ESXi runs best on
>   machines with such synchronized TSCs. ESXi also has support for
>   machines with unsynchronized TSCs, but with a significant performance
>   penalty.  In particular, executing the rdtsc instruction in a virtual
>   machine can be on the order of 100 times slower if the host has
>   unsynchronized TSCs.
>
> On a few current machines, ESXi incorrectly detects the host TSCs as
>   being unsynchronized because of a difference in interpretation of
>   certain ACPI table fields provided by firmware.  Currently, most HPE
>   Superdome series machines are affected by this issue.
>
> Resolution 
>   There is no resolution for the issue at the moment.
>
> Workaround 
>   Note:
>   Do not apply this setting on a machine that does not really have
>   synchronized TSCs.  If you do, the machine will eventually crash when
>   the TSCs drift too far apart, and there may be confusing symptoms
>   prior to the crash.
>
> If the host definitely has synchronized TSCs, you can force the
>   vmkernel to use the TSC as a global reference timer with the following
>   boot option:

```
esxcli system settings kernel set
 --setting=timerForceTSC --value=TRUE
```

As an alternative to the force TSC workaround, consider testing the host on an alternate hypervisor. Such as KVM, Hyper-V, or bare metal. In any case, mitigating this issue should be obvious with 100x less time spent in TSC functions.

### Application

`wl_ssl_conn_recv` is in the stack of 80% of the time. It must be a WebLogic function, as I'm not finding that in httpd source code.

Some of the time it spent is ultimately related to poll() and TSC, so checking for synchronized TSC first could be a quicker win. Still, look into [tuning WebLogic performance](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/PERFM/wls_tuning.htm).

### HTTPS conversations

Also analyze what the protocol conversations look like over the network. Namely, how is https performing. Try a packet capture and analysis, see what response times look like. Quantify the rate of connections, 30 per second is quite a bit different than 300.

Maybe there are efficiencies in implementing HTTP/2, but I don't know how to do that in WebLogic.

### Security Patches

A significant chunk of your on CPU time is syscall related. Evaluate what patches and mitigations you have enabled for [Spectre/Meltdown](https://access.redhat.com/articles/3311301)  and [MDS](https://access.redhat.com/security/vulnerabilities/mds). These have been known to have a relatively high performance hit on syscall heavy workloads. Test the various levels of mitigation, and make a risk assessment based on your overall security controls.

### Capacity Planning

Maybe 4 CPUs just isn't enough, at least how this system is currently tuned. Throwing hardware at the problem with more instances or more CPUs may not be efficient, but at least you can keep things responsive while tweaking other things.